# Should I see in-app-purchases in DebugView from TestFlight?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to track in-app-purchases in my app to Firebase. According to Firebase's documentation, it's automatically logs by framework. To test if I configure and install everything properly, I turn on debug mode by using `-FIRDebugEnabled` and go DebugView in Firebase console to check real-time events. In DebugView I can see some events triggers, like first_open, etc. BUT. If I make in-app-purchase (subscription), it's print out to Xcode console something like this and don't triggers in Firebase DebugView.

> Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: _iapx, {
> currency = USD;
> ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
> ga_event_origin (_o) = auto;
> ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
> price = 15990000;
> product_name = Premium 1 month.;
> quantity = 1;
> sandbox = 1;
> subscription = 1;
> value = 15990000;
> }

I suppose, maybe it's because I'm in Sandbox (Testflight) and this is not real in-app-purchase or I configure something wrong and event in debug mode also should works?

Answer (score 2):

After release my app to AppStore, Firebase started logging in app purchase events. So keep in mind: In Testflight you won't see those events, but after releasing it to the AppStore, everything will works great.